# Ubuntu don't boot after updating Windows (Dual-boot)

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have a dual-boot system with both W10 and Ubuntu 16.04.3 on it. First of all, after updating W10, the grub got broken and I used **Boot-Repair** for amending it. The operation was successful, though I got the following warning:

> The boot files of [Ubuntu 166.04.3 LTS] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4 > 200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then selec this partition via the [Separate/boot partitions] option of [Boot Repair].

After using Boot-Repair, the **GRUB loads correctly**, but when selecting the Ubuntu loader, the OS is not able to load. It get to a black "Emergency mode" screen, where I have access to a shell.

I also tried booting Ubuntu in **recovery mode**, and repairing the GRUB and the filesystem, but the problem persists. If I try to boot any other kernel, I get to the same "Emergency screen" appears.

Answer (score 0):

When installing Windows it scans through all `HDDs` looking for bootable partition. When it finds it - then format it. `Linux` partitions, such as `ext4` it sees as `unformatted` and format them too. Partitions such as `swap, root, etc.`

If you want to have a `dual-boot` system - you should first install `Windows`, and second install `Ubuntu` or any other `Linux`. And it is better to have physically separate `HDDs` for `Linux` and for `Windows` to be able to unplug `Linux` when you are updating or reinstalling `Windows`.

---

**4 partitions or separate `HDDs`:**

1. `swap` - capacity is identical to your physical memory size (for desktop, or 1/2 of physical memory size for server).
2. `root` or `/` - capacity see your system minimal requirements.
3. `Windows` or `C:\\` - capacity see your system minimal requirements.
4. `home` or `/home` - capacity is up to you so that you may fit all your applications (or all remaining disk space).

---

**What you can do now?**

- Try to boot from `Live Ubuntu` to rescue your files.
- Reinstall `Ubuntu`.